# How can i create/retrive more detailed participant info in twilio video?

Tags: video, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-video, twilio-node

I want to show multiple user details as an overlay on the participant's video.

Is there any way we can store more detailed participant data for the Twilio video?

I've used Twilio chat and we can store some app-related data in attributes. As shown [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/chat/rest/member-resource#:%7E:text=Member%20properties,-Each%20Member%20resource&text=The%20SID%20of%20the%20Channel%20the%20Member%20resource%20belongs%20to.&text=The%20SID%20of%20the%20Service%20the%20Member%20resource%20is%20associated%20with.&text=The%20application%2Ddefined%20string%20that,resource%27s%20User%20within%20the%20Service.&text=The%20JSON%20string%20that%20stores%20application%2Dspecific%20data.).

Just want to do the same thing in Twilio video.

Also, please suggest if there is any other way to achieve this.